# Returning results from a helper method

Tags: java, methods, helper

Say I have the following helper method

```
public int doTheSum(int num1, int num2)
{
    return num1 + num2;
}
```

And this method

```
public int doSum(int num1, int num2)
{
    return the answer from the helper method
}
```

So how do i get the method to return the result from the helper method

Comment: You can figure this out on your own, guaranteed. What do you think might work? What have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's as easy as that:

```
public int doSum(int num1, int num2)
{
    return doTheSum(num1,num2);
}
```

Comment: @user445714 Make sure you don't write `doTheSum` as `doSum`! You will get a `StackOverFlow` error!

Comment: spoon-feeding wins out. It's hard to believe that the original poster of the question was unable to try and show a solution on their own first. It's worse that you and the rest didn't let him do so.

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels, I actually felt that it was kinda wrong to respond to such kind of question, but than I thought that user445714 is probably making his/her first steps in programming (and I remember how frustrating this could be).

Comment: I remember that too, but I also remember learning more if I were nudged into a solution rather than given a solution, hence my question to the OP in the comment to his original post (which he never answered -- but of course he didn't have to since he was given solutions).

Answer (score 0):

```
public int doSum(int num1, int num2)
{    
   return doTheSum(num1, num2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public int doSum(int num1, int num2)
{
    return this.doTheSum(num1, num2)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

That would just be a method call to the `doTheSum` method:

```
public int doSum(int num1, int num2)
{
    return doTheSum(num1, num2);
}
```